# Orthogonal projection onto the subspace space spanned by itself?

Tags: orthogonality

Let $v$ be any nonzero n-vector. What is the orthogonal projector onto the subspace spanned by $v$?

How would I begin to answer this question?

Comment: It is the matrix $u u^T$, where $u$ is the unit vector in the direction $v$. Just Google search "projection matrix". This is the 1-dimensional special case.

Comment: Adding to Nick, think about it as a generalization of a simple $\mathbb R^n$ vector space, where the inner product is the scalar product, where $w\cdot v = |w|\cdot|v|\cos \theta$ . So you just need to normalize it and "vectorize" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of dot product, it is the map:
$$u\longmapsto \frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}v$$